# If $z'$ be the conjugate of the complex

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z'$ be the conjugate of the complex number $z$, prove that: $\textrm {Arg} (z')=2π-\textrm {Arg} (z)$.

I didn't get any idea. Please help.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: Hint: Draw a picture of $\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{R}^2$ with $z$ and $z'$

Answer (score 1):

For some positive $R$ in real numbers we define $z$ as $Re^{i \alpha}$, $\alpha$ being the  argument of $z$. Now observe that since $e^{i \alpha}=cos( \alpha )$ + $i sin( \alpha)$, $e^{i \alpha}=e^{i ( \alpha + 2 \pi)}$ since $cos$ and $sin$ are periodic functions. Conjugate of $z$ is defined as $Re^{-i \alpha}$. Similar thing as above can be said for conjugate of the $z$. So for conjugate of $z$ we get $Re^{-i( \alpha - 2 \pi)}=Re^{i(2\pi - \alpha)}$ by definition the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider $$z=ai+b,\quad a\in\mathbb{R},\ b\in\mathbb{R}$$
then we can draw the point $A$ affected by the coordinates $(a,b)=(\Re(z),\Im(z))$

And we know that $z'=\bar{z}=-ai+b$ then the point $B$ affected by the coordinates $(-a,b)$ is the symmetrical point of the point $A$ with respect to the $(Ox)$ axis